# I want all meta descriptions and meta keywords in one file

Tags: meta-tags

I have multiple pages with different meta keywords and meta descriptions.
I want the meta description and meta keyword to be compiled in one file and i need a code which can retrieve the specific meta data form the list to each page. I want to keep different meta keywords and meta description to different pages, but just want all of them in one single file.

Which means, once the code is run, all pages, should be able to get their respective meta tags from this list. Hope i am clear.

I had tried to work down as below:

Meta tags in the file:

```
$meta['keywords'] = "Keyoword, more words, ...";
$mtea['description'] = "...";
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Defining in index.php

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $meta['keywords']; ?>" />
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $mtea['description']; ?>" />
```

But this didnt work.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I dont know how to start with. I am new for this. Request your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - please break down your question to a code example and do not expect someone to write a programm.